# How to solve a general recurrence?

Tags: math, recurrence

Is there a way to solve a general recurrence relation of the form

```
a(n)=a(n-1) * a(n-2)....
```

I mean I can use the matrix method to solve a relation of the form

```
F(n)=a1*F(n-1) + a2*F(n-2).......+ ak*F(n-k)
```

but what to do when there is a `'*'` sign instead of `'+'`

Comment: You should submit this to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/). This isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logarithms:

```
a(n) = a(n-1) * a(n-2) * a(n-3) * ....
```

Take log of both sides:

```
log(a(n)) = log(a(n-1) * a(n-2) * a(n-3) * ...)
```

Use the fact that `log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b)` to split up the factors:

```
log(a(n)) = log(a(n-1)) + log(a(n-2)) + log(a(n-3)) + ...
```

Now, if you just say that `F(n) = log(a(n))` then this equation looks just like your second equation. Use the matrix method to solve for `log(a(n))`:

```
log(a(n)) = X
```

Which leaves:

```
a(n) = e ^ X
```

(Assuming you take natural logarithms)